# Creating tokens on BSC mainnet vs BSC testnet

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, testnets, bsc, smart-contract-wallets

I am starting to test with creating tokens. My contracts deploy correctly in mainnet but fail to deploy on testnet (the transaction gets reverted).

1. What are the main differences between mainnet and testnet? Is there any important difference that could explain this problem?
2. How can I debug why a transaction that deploys a contract gets reverted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There should be no error. Can you check:

1. Is it the same contract you deployed main net?
2. Are you selecting right compiler version for deploying to test net?

If is there still error, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same contract that I am deploying in the mainnet. I am using the same compiler version in both mainnet and testnet, should I not do that?

Comment: This is interesting. Can you give me the contract code that you are trying to deploy?

Comment: Are you willing to chat on discord / skype / telegram?

Comment: Telegram or Discord sounds good.

Comment: i know this is late but once look here.. none of us able to deploy on testnet. have a look.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117108/sc-not-deploying-and-getting-fail-pending-everytime