# SC not deploying and getting fail/pending everytime

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, bscscan

I have been trying to deploy SC, but every time transaction goes into pending state.
Tried with many SC but even simplest SC is not getting deploy since sunday.
I am using remix IDE over injected web3 and doing transaction on BSC testnet.
refer below image.. is something wrong with SC.

[image]

Comment: Could you share the tx hash of the pending transaction?

Comment: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x9a8847573bf15804766c9ab840b6b7120aced2e79740720440876651afcba512
sometimes it says could not find hash and sometimes shows in pending state..
I asked few of my colleagues to do same ,, all are facing same issue i.e no one is able to deploy over testnet

Comment: Someone please help.. we need to deploy and test many SC. is there community where I can contact regards BSC testnet deployment issues .. none of our colleagues are able to deploy..

Comment: Do you have a previous pending transaction?

Comment: there is more than 25 queued in matamask for deployment and eveytime hash is coming as https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x9a8847573bf15804766c9ab840b6b7120aced2e79740720440876651afcba512

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i might not be able to help you , but it does seems to look like some issue maybe from network end.
I tried the exact same thing and it worked like a charm. Maybe some network issues. Try to disconnect from vpn if you are connected to one.

Also try to change the version of solidity to 0.4.17

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend to use such an old solidity version. In general you should stick to one of the newer version (e.g. 0.8.x) unless you have a very good reason not to ;)

Comment: @amit, i am not on VPN and asked my colleagues to do.. everyone is facing same issue.. no one is able to deploy on testnet