# Rinkeby Faucet not loading Ether after social media post

Tags: ether, rinkeby

i'm trying to acquire some Ether for development/testing using Rinkeby faucet, gone through the twitter process and added my account to the tweet:

0xC06935C74194253A54B2d2eD7185371C4C061E48

But when I copy the url to Rinkey Faucet and request some ether I get a message saying "Insufficient funds for gas * price + value"

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last transaction on rinkeby went through 3 days ago, so it's probably out of service righ now.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Will keep checking back to see when its back up and running

Comment: HI, is BSCtestnet also out of service, please look at this question
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117108/sc-not-deploying-and-getting-fail-pending-everytime